# Distributed Caching to avoid duplicate requests

Tags: java, distributed, distributed-caching

Multiple instances of the same ServiceA are running on different jvm's. But they are all sharing the same backend data from a DB

When there is a request from the client, ServiceA looks up if the data is available in it's DB, if not it requests another ServiceB to get that data and store that in it's DB and returns it back to the client.

If two clients request at the same time and two instances of ServiceA handle those requests, both those instance can effectively call ServiceB to get that data. How should i handle this case so that there will only be one request to SerivceB.

Answer (score 1):

Two add to what [@norbert-van-nobelen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37819772/364274) said;

There are two more possibilities.

- One is to let your ServiceB decide which request to process
- The other option is to allow your ServiceA to sync with your ServiceB and deal with the race condition.

Since the description of your services are very abstract to me, you could implement something as a distributed lock in your serviceB or incorporate a distributed cache to do it for you.

an example; http://blogs.alachisoft.com/distributed-locking/

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is apply a hash to the request, and check in the request queue if the request is present already.

To get that to work effectively you also need to know where you send a hashed request in case of multiple caching servers:

> Suppose you 2 caching back ends: You want to be fault tolerant and efficient.
>
> Efficient: This can be done with a simple MODULUS over the hash in which the modulus determines to which server you talk
>
> Fault tolerant has to be part of the communication layer where you determine if your caching back end is actually available and where you determine how to fall back.